# Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: exception, log4j, nullpointerexception

I'm using eclipse, apache tomcat 6.0.32, Struts, Hibernate and obviously, log4j - which seems to be causing the problem. Since I'm really new to all of these technologies, I am unsure how to even start debugging the problem.

Since I'm not sure what kind of info I should provide, I'll just post the exception here:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog$Log4jMLogger.isLoggable(Log4jMLog.java:255)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$CheckIdleResourcesTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1961)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And my log4j.properties file:

```
# Output at info level, to the appender called 'A'. Debug has too much logging.
log4j.rootLogger=info, A
# Configure the appender called 'A'
log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you give some more information like when you see this exception? Is Eclipse set to automatically re-deploy the project on change? If so, that can cause some odd issues.

Comment: I see the exception when I start the server.. Though oddly enough, now I notice that it appears once, then doesn't once :O

Comment: Found any solution? I've got the same issue in Eclipse (in combination with Maven and Tocmat 7)

Answer (score 0):

Hello Noy you might be creating `Timer` object in Local and might be scheduling at particular time, For my side the same error resolved by creating `Timer` object to global keyboard.
Use bellow line after declaring class. It should work.
`Timer timer = new Timer();`